# Media query working only for SOME properties

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

The media query defined for fitting tablets does change some of the properties but it doesn't react at all for some other. Please see below which are working fine and which ones not.

```
// MEDIA FOR TABLET SIZE

@media (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 768px){

main{

    .top{

        .top-right{
            display: none;   // Works fine
        }

        .top-left{
            background-color: white; // Works fine
            width: 20%;                // DOESNT WORK
            align-items: center;

            .top-left-content{
                margin-left: 0px;
            }

        }
    }


    .bottom{
        background:white;           // DOESNT WORK

        .bottom-left{
            display: none;            //works fine
            width: 100%;              //DOESNT WORK
            background-color: red;  //Works fine
        }


    }
 }


}
```

here part of the HTML for the top container as reference:

```
<main>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="top-left">
            <div class="top-left-content">
                <h2>Capture <span>Life</span></h2>
                <p>A fun and easy way to capture &amp; share the moments you live</br>for</p>
                 <div>
                     <img src="img/icon_app_store.png">
                     <img src="img/icon_google_play.png">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="top-right">
                <img src="img/site_phone.png">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you override them somewhere else? Show us the styling for all other possible media queries you use?

Comment: And take a look on the class .bottom-left: You use display: none to hide it and you write it works. So if it works, it's not there anymore and than the width: 100% also has no logic there.

Comment: Yes you are right, the purpose is only to verify that some properties are working

Comment: #MrBuggy: I don't think I am overriding, since this is the only media im using. Then you are right about the non logic of having display: none and then wchange the width to 100%. I just have it like this to show that some properties work (diplay: none) but some other dont (width: 100%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the element in firefox or chrome to see where the styles are coming from - this may reveal that you are overiding them elsewhere if this is the case and you can't change the overriding styles you can add !important like this -

```
.top-left{

        background-color: white; 
        width: 20% !important;               
        align-items: center;
```

Also, as was pointed out in the comments, if you are hiding an element with display:none what is the purpose of adding width: 100% and background-color:red; ?

Answer (score -1):

Need to USE important Or use Body before class

```
boday .yourclass{ }
```

Comment: PERFECT THAT WAS IT ! It works now. Thank you very much @Ashar Zafar